# I want to offer template editing like tumblr in my web app; what are my security considerations?

Tags: php, security, xss, twig, tumblr

I'm using php and the twig template engine, i want my users to be able to design the complete html document that will be output. I need them to be able to include scripts, and css from external sources.

What do I need to do to completely lock down my app for security?

What steps do tumblr take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any solutions to keep your project 100% secure. However, you could take some actions and check users html files for malware code by certain period of time. I am not completely sure, but I think there are some free good API's which will do that job for you. I don't know about Tumblr a lot, but I think they are using some kind of API for javascript check.

Comment: No, the are not. Full access to html source of your blog. There are some other security solutions.

Comment: this answer is correct, i found that its difficult to think of every vector of attack.